# How can I compare each word from a string to a whole column in Exel?

Tags: excel

[image: Excel Image]

Hi guys, I have columns A, B, and C. Now I need to compare values of Column C to Column A & B to create something like Column D. I have too little knowledge of Excel so I cannot find out the way to write the correct formula for Column D. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Will cells in column `A` only ever contain one Kanji? Also, my Japanese is limited, but shouldn't 日 read DAY in this context?

Comment: Only one Kanji in column A. And yes, 日 for day would be better. However, this is just to show how the results should look. I would refine the meaning later.